# how to read data from excel file in matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab, xlsread

I need to read data from my excel file in MATLAB, i need to read all the columns and rows , but i don't want the headers of the columns, i.e i need to start reading the data from second row onwards with all columns. can someone help me in this ?  my excel file look like this :

[image: excel file image]

the image is just for clarification , if you want my excel file i can attach that too.

i tried the following code but it also gives the headers text and the empty columns text

```
filename = 'C:\\Users\Zeeshan\Desktop\box_annotation.xlsx';
[subsetA txt]= xlsread(filename)
```

Comment: Did you try to use the `xrange`-Parameter of xlsread?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of `xlsread`, it allows to specify a range in excel syntax (`B1:F4`) but is only available in the recent Matlab Versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if it works

```
delimiter='';
A =importdata('Filename.xlsx',delimiter,1);

%Then to access the data, command can be given
A.data
```

Comment: but A.textdata.Sheet1 still contains empty columns data